# Can't solve floating point exception

Tags: c, floating-point, cs50

I am attempting to complete Problem Set 1 for CS50x by Harvard and I've come across a sort of bug in my program. It is throwing a floating point exception error at me; I've researched this quite a bit and it seems to mostly be caused when you attempt to divide by zero. Now when I look at my code, I can't seem to find a single place where a variable is even equal to zero let alone divided by zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int changeF(change, div)
{
    int c = change/div;
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the bill amount:");
    float bill = GetFloat();
    printf("Enter the payment amount:");
    float payment = GetFloat();
    float q = .25; float di = .1; float n = .05; float p = .01;
    float change = payment - bill;
    do
    {
        if (bill >= 0 && payment >= 0 && change >= 0)
        {
            if (change >= q)
            {
                float quarters = changeF(change, q);
                printf("%f quarters", quarters);
                change = change - (.25*quarters);
            }
            if (change >= di)
            {
                float dimes = changeF(change, di);
                printf("%f dimes", dimes);
                change = change - (.1*dimes);
            }
            if (change >= n)
            {   
                float nickels = changeF(change, n);
                printf("%f nickels", nickels);
                change = change - (.05*nickels);
            }
            if (change >= p)
            {
                float pennies = changeF(change, p);
                printf("%f pennies", pennies);
                change = change - (.01*pennies);
            }
        }
    }
    while (change > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give type to the function arguments:

```
 changeF(float change, float div)
```

I'm not sure if you really want the return of this function to be int or float!

Answer (score 1):

Your `changeF()` function is written:

```
int changeF(change, div)
{
    int c = change/div;
    return c;
}
```

That is using the old (C89, or pre-standard — not more recent C99 or C11) notation for a function, implicitly declaring `changeF()` to take two `int` arguments.

When you call `changeF()` with a `float` value that's less than 1.0 for the `div` argument, it gets converted to an `int` value of `0`.  You then divide by that zero, yielding your FPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
int changeF(change, div)
```

The problem is in this function. It's return type is `int` so, when `c` have value `0.1`,`0.2` or something like that it becomes `0` and returns it. Another problem is you didn't specify the data type in the definition (old style K&R pre-standard function definition). That's why it takes the default data type and default data type is `int`.

You should update the code in the following way.

```
double changeF(double change, double div)
```